# Error connecting jupyter notebook 5.0 in root environment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-console

I've been using jupyter notebook in my root environment and a few other environment for several months. Upgraded to jupyter notebook 5 last week and it worked well until yesterday.

Yesterday - computer froze. After restarting, jupyter notebook gives an error (2x) when launched from root environment:

(some info replaced with # below)

```
[I 08:57:31.223 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: #######
[I 08:57:31.223 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 08:57:31.223 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=########################
[I 08:57:31.223 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 08:57:31.224 NotebookApp]  
    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=########################
[I 08:57:32.992 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[I 08:58:01.367 NotebookApp] Kernel started: ###########
[I 08:58:02.775 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel ############
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.version
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.version
```

I've tried copying and pasting the link provided above. It removed one of the error messages next time it was launched, then 2 error messages after trying to launch again.

Jupyter notebook works when launched from a different conda environment.

Any thoughts on how to get this working in my root environment again?

Comment: I think you can safely ignore those error messages if the notebook otherwise works. If you need ipywidgets, make sure it's installed in your root environment. https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html

Comment: The notebook does not work. It launches the first page, but anytime I open a .ipynb file, it does not work. I tried installing ipywidgets, but it says it's already installed.

Comment: Have you run the `jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix` step?